# Set Properties in Toad Data Point Fails

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, toad

I am using Toad Data Point V4.0 to connect to Hive. I try to set below properties using Toad.

- set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat;
- set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
- set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge=true;

While I can set these properties via Beeline, TOAD throws below error when running above set commands.

> [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify input.format at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime

Wondering if I have to set these properties somewhere in connection setup or not. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

We've found a very similar issue with DBVis on Hive.

DBVis is stripping the ‘hive.’ off of commands like “set hive.mapred.mode=strict”. It then checks hive’s list of parameters allowed to be set at runtime for the parameter: “mapred.mode” instead of “hive.mapred.mode”. Since it does not find the parameter, it throws and error.

If we preface the parameter by a second “hive.” (for example, “hive.hive.mapred.mode=strict”) DBVis appears to strips off the first “hive.”. It then finds the stripped version as allowed and sends the stripped version to hive where is executes fine.

NB: This only seems to affect parameters beginning with "hive.".